# HID descriptor + report for iOS Home button?

Tags: hid, usb-descriptor

I'm trying to use an Arduino to create a single-button Bluetooth keyboard and struggling to construct a valid HID descriptor. I've been able to send key events to my iOS device using the default generic desktop keyboard HID descriptor, but once I try using the following HID descriptor I'm unable to trigger a home button event (AC Home: 0x0223) when I send HID reports to toggle bit 0 from 0 → 1 → 0:

```
0x05, 0x0c,       // USAGE_PAGE (Consumer Devices)
 0x09, 0x01,      // USAGE (Consumer Control)
 0xa1, 0x01,      // COLLECTION (Application)
 0x15, 0x00,      // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
 0x25, 0x01,      // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
 0x75, 0x01,      // REPORT_SIZE (1)
 0x95, 0x01,      // REPORT_COUNT (1)
 0x0c, 0x02, 0x23 // USAGE (AC Home)
 0x81, 0x06,      // INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
 0x95, 0x07,      // REPORT_COUNT (7 bytes of padding)
 0x81, 0x03,      // INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
 0xc0             // END_COLLECTION
```

Am I missing something in the construction of my HID descriptor? Is AC Home not the correct usage ID for the home button in iOS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've also tried Consumer usage IDs for "mute" (0xe2) and "volume down" (0xec) and those aren't working either, which is what leads me to believe my HID descriptor is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a small error in your descriptor:

```
0x0c, 0x02, 0x23 // USAGE (AC Home)
```

should be:

```
0x0a, 0x23, 0x02 // USAGE (AC Home)
```

Your current descriptor decodes as:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0C        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page 
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0001 Consumer Control (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000C0001: Page=Consumer Device Page, Usage=Consumer Control, Type=Application Collection)
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
0C             (ERROR)                     <-- Error: Item (0C) is not a MAIN, GLOBAL or LOCAL item
02 2381        (MAIN)                      <-- Error: Item (02) is not a MAIN item. Expected INPUT(8x) OUTPUT(9x) FEATURE(Bx) COLLECTION(Ax) or END_COLLECTION(Cx) (where x = 0,1,2,3).
06 9507        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0795 Reserved 
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reserved inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: CA:ConsumerControl
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport_t;
```

After the above change is implemented it looks in better shape:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0C        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page 
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0001 Consumer Control (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000C0001: Page=Consumer Device Page, Usage=Consumer Control, Type=Application Collection)
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
0A 2302        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0223 AC Home (Selector)  
81 06          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 07          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x07 (7) Number of fields  
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (7 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Consumer Device Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: CA:ConsumerControl
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlAcHome : 1;             // Usage 0x000C0223: AC Home, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport_t;
```

...the HID descriptor was decoded with hidrdd (freeware) from [github](https://github.com/abend0c1/hidrdd) or [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/)